# Does the Devi Bhagavatam mention in which Kalpa was it written?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, devi-bhagavata-purana, matsya-purana

The Matsya Purana states that the Srimad Bhagavatam was written in the Saraswati Kalpa? Does the Devi Bhagavatam mention in which Kalpa was it written?

Comment: But srimad Bhagavatam says it was written in this Kalpa

Comment: @Ajay In the Svetavaraha kalpa?

Comment: Yeah.Come to chat room

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it mentions. It was composed in the SArasvat Kalpa.

> 26-40. Vyâsa said :-- O King! Maharsi Nârada thus kindling knowledge
>   in me, went away; I also thought over his words. On the banks of the
>   river Sarasvatî, **I composed this Devî Bhâgavat to pass away my time
>   during the excellent period of Sârasvata Kalpa.** This Purânam is
>   excellent; it is composed on the authority of the the Vedas; all
>   doubts are removed by it; many nice events are narrated here.
>
> **From the [31st chapter of the 6th book, named the "Glory of MahAmAyA" in the Devi BhAgavatam.](http://www.astrojyoti.com/devibhagavatam31-6.htm)**